# iPhone getting value to two different textfields from single method

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Using the below code, the issue is I have two buttons and two textfields but I am getting the qrcode value using single method. How can i use it for two textfields

```
- (IBAction) keyScanButtonTapped
{

NSLog(@"TBD: scan barcode here...");

// ADD: present a barcode reader that scans from the camera feed
ZBarReaderViewController *reader = [ZBarReaderViewController new];
reader.readerDelegate = self;
reader.supportedOrientationsMask = ZBarOrientationMaskAll;

ZBarImageScanner *scanner = reader.scanner;
// TODO: (optional) additional reader configuration here

// EXAMPLE: disable rarely used I2/5 to improve performance
[scanner setSymbology: ZBAR_I25 config: ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE to: 0];

// present and release the controller
[self presentModalViewController: reader animated: YES];

[reader release];

}

-(void) imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController*) reader didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary*) info
{

// ADD: get the decode results

id<NSFastEnumeration> results = [info objectForKey: ZBarReaderControllerResults];

ZBarSymbol *symbol = nil;

for(symbol in results)
    // EXAMPLE: just grab the first barcode
    break;

// EXAMPLE: do something useful with the barcode data

deviceKey.text = symbol.data;

// EXAMPLE: do something useful with the barcode image

resultImage.image = [info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

// ADD: dismiss the controller (NB dismiss from the *reader*!)
[reader dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];
}
```

Comment: Maybe that is just me but this question does not seem to make any sense. I would suggest you to enhance your original question with further details. What should happen in which sequence?

Comment: Look at the spec -- the action method accepts a parameter which is a pointer to the button touched.  Compare that to the two buttons linked to it to see which one was touched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you simply want to connect two different buttons to this same function?  That is no problem just go into interface builder and connect both buttons to this method.  You can see this question on how to connect buttons in interface builder

[How can I connect "File's Owner" with a button in a Toolbar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096427/how-can-i-connect-files-owner-with-a-button-in-a-toolbar)

when the callback function is called you can identify which button called the function in such a manner

```
-(void)buttonPressed:(id)sender{
    //find out which button was pressed
    UIButton * pressed = (UIButton*) sender;
    NSInteger tag = pressed.tag;
}
```

the tags are defined in the interface builder, just make sure that they are different for the two buttons and you are good to go.

Comment: i know its easy to connect two buttons with a single method... actually the method keyScanButtonTapped is calling a delegate method (-(void) imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController*) reader didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary*) info
{) of qrcode reader framework, here in this delegate method only a single textfield is being assigned the data (deviceKey.text = symbol.data;). i want to know how can i assign symbol.data to deviceID.text. so that when one button is tapped, data dud be assigned to deviceKey textfield and on other button tap should be assigned to deviceID textfield

Comment: see the updated answer on how to identify which button was pressed and then just pass that data on to the following functions.

Comment: can you be more specific on what didn't work?  I know that this tactic works because I use it several times in my own code.  Did you remember to change the tag in Interface Builder for one of the buttons?

Comment: i don't know ... i might be wrong in code.. its not giving me any error ...can u help me with code example

Comment: I put the code example in the answer.  The other thing you need to do is go to Interface Builder and set the tag for the buttons.  Here is a video on Interface Builder if you don't know what that is

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aeJ7OZG8VFo